# Sorting array in java using a reference point

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Suppose I have an ArrayList of 2D coordinates like *L1* and two other points *a* and *b*. Note that all of the coordinates in *L1* are on the line segment *ab*.
I want to sort *L1* by the distance from point *a* such that the closest points to *a* are stored first.
I know that I need to write a comparator to use it to sort *L1* but first, I have little knowledge about the comparator interface, and second, every reading material I found just compared two elements by each other unlike here that I need a third element as a reference point. Is it even possible to do such?
I would appreciate some reading material (for this kind of advanced sorting stuff) about the subject along with your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here: First there's the math. If I understand correctly, you're effectively going to compare `Math.abs(a-L1)` and `Math.abs(b-L1)` so we would have a closure like

```
myArrayList.sort((a,b) -> Double.compare(Math.abs(a-L1), Math.abs(b-L1)));
```

but since `L1` is used inside the lambda, it must be effectively final so we will need to have `L1` initialized as final:

```
final double L1 = 42;
```

Of course in your case you need to replace `Math.abs` with an appropriate function that measures the distance from a point `a` to `L1` and initialize `L1` appropriately with an instance of your 2D coordinates.

Comment: Well not exactly, imagine two elements in L1 like p and q, I need to compare `Math.abs(a-p)` and `Math.abs(a-q)` to each other in order to determine which comes first in the sorted list. Note that L1 is an ArrayList of points.

Comment: @ARK1375 That's what the `Double.compare` does. Replace `Math.abs` with a distance function for your 2D points and you're done.

Comment: I tested it today and it worked fine, thanks ;)